# Multiple JQuery Accordian Menus - Remember unique states with cookies (persist state)

Tags: jquery, cookies, accordion, state

I am new to jquery and need some help here. I am using an accordion menu based on CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery [see original version](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-urban.htm)... I have a question that I hope some guru here can answer... My experience comes from ASP and ActionScript so I need some direction or help here!

I had no issue setting up and tweaking the menu and setting it to save its open state, BUT the website I am working on is quite large and menus do change entirely from one website section to another. The problem is the saved open state from one menu is passed to all the other menus in other sections of the website. Example: If the saved open state from menu 1 is header two, then the user navigates to a another section of the website with menu 2, the menu opens the saved state of menu 1 which is header two and this becomes very odd. I know that this is done via a cookie that expires at the end of session and the value passed for that cookie is somthing like c0, c1, c2 and so on. c0 being header 1, c1 being header 2 and so on. I also know that I can pass a query string with every menu request to open a certain header item, such as `www.example.com/company/?headerbar=2` but this is not ideal.

The problem is that I am using the same class for the header bars with all the menus and the jQuery core and accordion JavaScript and CSS are all server side includes that are loaded in all the website sections where the menu appears.

**My question is:** Is there a way to make the cookie that remembers which header group is open unique per menu? May be by appending something else to the cookie such as the url location of the menu so that each unique menu can remember its own unique saved state? My javascript skills are improving but I cannot figure out all the cookies functions and code being implemented in the sidemenu.js file in order to make the necessary changes.

The original menu is here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-urban.htm

I am using jQuery v1.7.2

#### Menu html

```
<div class="ws_sidemenu">
  <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">CSS Library</a></h3>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Horizontal CSS Menus?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vertical CSS Menus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Image CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Form CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DIVs and containers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links & Buttons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse All</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">JavaScript Kit</a></h3>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#" >Free JavaScripts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DHTML & CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Free Java Applets</a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Here is my CSS which is a server-side include in every section where the menu appears

```
.ws_sidemenu{
  width:200px; /*width of menu*/
  padding-right:10px;
}
/* 1. Side Menu Header Bar */
.ws_sidemenu .headerbar{
  font:bold 13px Verdana;
  color:white;
  background:#606060 url(/media/images/gui/arrows/arw_white_sm_sidemenu.png) no-repeat 4px 13px;; /*last 2 values are the x and y coordinates of bullet image*/
  margin-bottom:0px; /*bottom spacing between header and rest of content*/
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 20px; /*last value is left indentation of header text*/
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:1px;
}
.ws_sidemenu .headerbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  outline:none;
}
/* 2. Side Menu Items */
.ws_sidemenu ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin-bottom:0; /*bottom spacing between each UL and rest of content*/
}
.ws_sidemenu ul li{
  padding-bottom:2px; /*bottom spacing between menu items*/
}
.ws_sidemenu ul li a{
  font:normal 12px Arial;
  color:black;
  background:#E0DDD8;
  display:block;
  padding:5px 0;
  line-height:17px;
  padding-left:8px; /*link text is indented*/
  padding-right:8px; /*link text is indented*/
  text-decoration:none;
  outline:none;
}
.ws_sidemenu ul li a:visited{
  color:black;
}
.ws_sidemenu ul li a:hover{ /*hover state CSS*/
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

#### HTML head script (which is a server-side include in every section where the menu appears)

```
<!--SIDE MENU - BEGIN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sidemenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sidemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  sidemenu.init({
    headerclass: "headerbar", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
    contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
    revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
    mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
    collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
    defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content - This can also be dobe by passing QS headerbar
    onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
    animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
    persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
    toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
    togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
    animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
    oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initialized - Highlighting headers that are expanded by default when the page loads
      for (var i=0; i<expandedindices.length; i++){
        var expandedindex=expandedindices[i] //index of current expanded header index within array
        headers[expandedindex].style.backgroundColor='#333333'
        headers[expandedindex].style.color='#fff'
      }
    },
    onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){
      //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
      //do nothing
    }
  })
</script>
```

#### Menu JavaScript file (Also Server-side include in every section where the menu appears)

```
/*
SIDE MENU
Version : 1.0
*/

var sidemenu={
    ajaxloadingmsg: '<img src="loading2.gif" /><br />Loading Content...', //customize HTML to output while Ajax content is being fetched (if applicable)

    headergroup: {}, //object to store corresponding header group based on headerclass value
    contentgroup: {}, //object to store corresponding content group based on headerclass value

    preloadimages:function($images){
        $images.each(function(){
            var preloadimage=new Image()
            preloadimage.src=this.src
        })
    },

    expandone:function(headerclass, selected, scrolltoheader){ //PUBLIC function to expand a particular header
        this.toggleone(headerclass, selected, "expand", scrolltoheader)
    },

    collapseone:function(headerclass, selected){ //PUBLIC function to collapse a particular header
        this.toggleone(headerclass, selected, "collapse")
    },

    expandall:function(headerclass){ //PUBLIC function to expand all headers based on their shared CSS classname
        var $headers=this.headergroup[headerclass]
        this.contentgroup[headerclass].filter(':hidden').each(function(){
            $headers.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('contentindex'))).trigger("evt_accordion")
        })
    },

    collapseall:function(headerclass){ //PUBLIC function to collapse all headers based on their shared CSS classname
        var $headers=this.headergroup[headerclass]
        this.contentgroup[headerclass].filter(':visible').each(function(){
            $headers.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('contentindex'))).trigger("evt_accordion")
        })
    },

    toggleone:function(headerclass, selected, optstate, scrolltoheader){ //PUBLIC function to expand/ collapse a particular header
        var $targetHeader=this.headergroup[headerclass].eq(selected)
        var $subcontent=this.contentgroup[headerclass].eq(selected)
        if (typeof optstate=="undefined" || optstate=="expand" && $subcontent.is(":hidden") || optstate=="collapse" && $subcontent.is(":visible"))
            $targetHeader.trigger("evt_accordion", [false, scrolltoheader])
    },

    ajaxloadcontent:function($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, callback){
        var ajaxinfo=$targetHeader.data('ajaxinfo')

        function handlecontent(content){ //nested function
            if (content){ //if ajax content has loaded
                ajaxinfo.cacheddata=content //remember ajax content 
                ajaxinfo.status="cached" //set ajax status to cached
                if ($targetContent.queue("fx").length==0){ //if this content isn't currently expanding or collapsing
                    $targetContent.hide().html(content) //hide loading message, then set sub content's HTML to ajax content
                    ajaxinfo.status="complete" //set ajax status to complete
                    callback() //execute callback function- expand this sub content
                }
            }
            if (ajaxinfo.status!="complete"){
                setTimeout(function(){handlecontent(ajaxinfo.cacheddata)}, 100) //call handlecontent() again until ajax content has loaded (ajaxinfo.cacheddata contains data)
            }
        } //end nested function

        if (ajaxinfo.status=="none"){ //ajax data hasn't been fetched yet
            $targetContent.html(this.ajaxloadingmsg)
            $targetContent.slideDown(config.animatespeed)
            ajaxinfo.status="loading" //set ajax status to "loading"
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxinfo.url, //path to external menu file
                error:function(ajaxrequest){
                    handlecontent('Error fetching content. Server Response: '+ajaxrequest.responseText)
                },
                success:function(content){
                    content=(content=="")? " " : content //if returned content is empty, set it to "space" is content no longer returns false/empty (hasn't loaded yet)
                    handlecontent(content)
                }
            })
        }
        else if (ajaxinfo.status=="loading")
            handlecontent(ajaxinfo.cacheddata)
    },

    expandit:function($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, useractivated, directclick, skipanimation, scrolltoheader){
        var ajaxinfo=$targetHeader.data('ajaxinfo')
        if (ajaxinfo){ //if this content should be fetched via Ajax
            if (ajaxinfo.status=="none" || ajaxinfo.status=="loading")
                this.ajaxloadcontent($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, function(){sidemenu.expandit($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, useractivated, directclick)})
            else if (ajaxinfo.status=="cached"){
                $targetContent.html(ajaxinfo.cacheddata)
                ajaxinfo.cacheddata=null
                ajaxinfo.status="complete"
            }
        }
        this.transformHeader($targetHeader, config, "expand")
        $targetContent.slideDown(skipanimation? 0 : config.animatespeed, function(){
            config.onopenclose($targetHeader.get(0), parseInt($targetHeader.attr('headerindex')), $targetContent.css('display'), useractivated)
            if (scrolltoheader){
                var sthdelay=(config["collapseprev"])? 20 : 0
                clearTimeout(config.sthtimer)
                config.sthtimer=setTimeout(function(){sidemenu.scrollToHeader($targetHeader)}, sthdelay)
            }
            if (config.postreveal=="gotourl" && directclick){ //if revealtype is "Go to Header URL upon click", and this is a direct click on the header
                var targetLink=($targetHeader.is("a"))? $targetHeader.get(0) : $targetHeader.find('a:eq(0)').get(0)
                if (targetLink) //if this header is a link
                    setTimeout(function(){location=targetLink.href}, 200 + (scrolltoheader? 400+sthdelay : 0) ) //ignore link target, as window.open(targetLink, targetLink.target) doesn't work in FF if popup blocker enabled
            }
        })
    },

    scrollToHeader:function($targetHeader){
        sidemenu.$docbody.stop().animate({scrollTop: $targetHeader.offset().top}, 400)
    },

    collapseit:function($targetHeader, $targetContent, config, isuseractivated){
        this.transformHeader($targetHeader, config, "collapse")
        $targetContent.slideUp(config.animatespeed, function(){config.onopenclose($targetHeader.get(0), parseInt($targetHeader.attr('headerindex')), $targetContent.css('display'), isuseractivated)})
    },

    transformHeader:function($targetHeader, config, state){
        $targetHeader.addClass((state=="expand")? config.cssclass.expand : config.cssclass.collapse) //alternate btw "expand" and "collapse" CSS classes
        .removeClass((state=="expand")? config.cssclass.collapse : config.cssclass.expand)
        if (config.htmlsetting.location=='src'){ //Change header image (assuming header is an image)?
            $targetHeader=($targetHeader.is("img"))? $targetHeader : $targetHeader.find('img').eq(0) //Set target to either header itself, or first image within header
            $targetHeader.attr('src', (state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse) //change header image
        }
        else if (config.htmlsetting.location=="prefix") //if change "prefix" HTML, locate dynamically added ".accordprefix" span tag and change it
            $targetHeader.find('.accordprefix').html((state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse)
        else if (config.htmlsetting.location=="suffix")
            $targetHeader.find('.accordsuffix').html((state=="expand")? config.htmlsetting.expand : config.htmlsetting.collapse)
    },

    urlparamselect:function(headerclass){
        var result=window.location.search.match(new RegExp(headerclass+"=((\\d+)(,(\\d+))*)", "i")) //check for "?headerclass=2,3,4" in URL
        if (result!=null)
            result=RegExp.$1.split(',')
        return result //returns null, [index], or [index1,index2,etc], where index are the desired selected header indices
    },

    getCookie:function(Name){ 
        var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i") //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
        if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
            return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
        return null
    },

    setCookie:function(name, value){
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/"
    },

    init:function(config){
    document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
    document.write('.'+config.contentclass+'{display: none}\n') //generate CSS to hide contents
    document.write('a.hiddenajaxlink{display: none}\n') //CSS class to hide ajax link
    document.write('<\/style>')
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        sidemenu.urlparamselect(config.headerclass)
        var persistedheaders=sidemenu.getCookie(config.headerclass)
        sidemenu.headergroup[config.headerclass]=$('.'+config.headerclass) //remember header group for this accordion
        sidemenu.contentgroup[config.headerclass]=$('.'+config.contentclass) //remember content group for this accordion
        sidemenu.$docbody=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? jQuery('html') : jQuery('body')) : jQuery('html,body')
        var $headers=sidemenu.headergroup[config.headerclass]
        var $subcontents=sidemenu.contentgroup[config.headerclass]
        config.cssclass={collapse: config.toggleclass[0], expand: config.toggleclass[1]} //store expand and contract CSS classes as object properties
        config.revealtype=config.revealtype || "click"
        config.revealtype=config.revealtype.replace(/mouseover/i, "mouseenter")
        if (config.revealtype=="clickgo"){
            config.postreveal="gotourl" //remember added action
            config.revealtype="click" //overwrite revealtype to "click" keyword
        }
        if (typeof config.togglehtml=="undefined")
            config.htmlsetting={location: "none"}
        else
            config.htmlsetting={location: config.togglehtml[0], collapse: config.togglehtml[1], expand: config.togglehtml[2]} //store HTML settings as object properties
        config.oninit=(typeof config.oninit=="undefined")? function(){} : config.oninit //attach custom "oninit" event handler
        config.onopenclose=(typeof config.onopenclose=="undefined")? function(){} : config.onopenclose //attach custom "onopenclose" event handler
        var lastexpanded={} //object to hold reference to last expanded header and content (jquery objects)
        var expandedindices=sidemenu.urlparamselect(config.headerclass) || ((config.persiststate && persistedheaders!=null)? persistedheaders : config.defaultexpanded)
        if (typeof expandedindices=='string') //test for string value (exception is config.defaultexpanded, which is an array)
            expandedindices=expandedindices.replace(/c/ig, '').split(',') //transform string value to an array (ie: "c1,c2,c3" becomes [1,2,3]
        if (expandedindices.length==1 && expandedindices[0]=="-1") //check for expandedindices value of [-1], indicating persistence is on and no content expanded
            expandedindices=[]
        if (config["collapseprev"] && expandedindices.length>1) //only allow one content open?
            expandedindices=[expandedindices.pop()] //return last array element as an array (for sake of jQuery.inArray())
        if (config["onemustopen"] && expandedindices.length==0) //if at least one content should be open at all times and none are, open 1st header
            expandedindices=[0]
        $headers.each(function(index){ //loop through all headers
            var $header=$(this)
            if (/(prefix)|(suffix)/i.test(config.htmlsetting.location) && $header.html()!=""){ //add a SPAN element to header depending on user setting and if header is a container tag
                $('<span class="accordprefix"></span>').prependTo(this)
                $('<span class="accordsuffix"></span>').appendTo(this)
            }
            $header.attr('headerindex', index+'h') //store position of this header relative to its peers
            $subcontents.eq(index).attr('contentindex', index+'c') //store position of this content relative to its peers
            var $subcontent=$subcontents.eq(index)
            var $hiddenajaxlink=$subcontent.find('a.hiddenajaxlink:eq(0)') //see if this content should be loaded via ajax
            if ($hiddenajaxlink.length==1){
                $header.data('ajaxinfo', {url:$hiddenajaxlink.attr('href'), cacheddata:null, status:'none'}) //store info about this ajax content inside header
            }
            var needle=(typeof expandedindices[0]=="number")? index : index+'' //check for data type within expandedindices array- index should match that type
            if (jQuery.inArray(needle, expandedindices)!=-1){ //check for headers that should be expanded automatically (convert index to string first)
                sidemenu.expandit($header, $subcontent, config, false, false, !config.animatedefault) //3rd last param sets 'isuseractivated' parameter, 2nd last sets isdirectclick, last sets skipanimation param
                lastexpanded={$header:$header, $content:$subcontent}
            }  //end check
            else{
                $subcontent.hide()
                config.onopenclose($header.get(0), parseInt($header.attr('headerindex')), $subcontent.css('display'), false) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter
                sidemenu.transformHeader($header, config, "collapse")
            }
        })
        //if (config["scrolltoheader"] && lastexpanded.$header)
            //sidemenu.scrollToHeader(lastexpanded.$header)
        $headers.bind("evt_accordion", function(e, isdirectclick, scrolltoheader){ //assign CUSTOM event handler that expands/ contacts a header
                var $subcontent=$subcontents.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('headerindex'))) //get subcontent that should be expanded/collapsed
                if ($subcontent.css('display')=="none"){
                    sidemenu.expandit($(this), $subcontent, config, true, isdirectclick, false, scrolltoheader) //2nd last param sets 'isuseractivated' parameter
                    if (config["collapseprev"] && lastexpanded.$header && $(this).get(0)!=lastexpanded.$header.get(0)){ //collapse previous content?
                        sidemenu.collapseit(lastexpanded.$header, lastexpanded.$content, config, true) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter
                    }
                    lastexpanded={$header:$(this), $content:$subcontent}
                }
                else if (!config["onemustopen"] || config["onemustopen"] && lastexpanded.$header && $(this).get(0)!=lastexpanded.$header.get(0)){
                    sidemenu.collapseit($(this), $subcontent, config, true) //Last Boolean value sets 'isuseractivated' parameter
                }
        })
        $headers.bind(config.revealtype, function(){
            if (config.revealtype=="mouseenter"){
                clearTimeout(config.revealdelay)
                var headerindex=parseInt($(this).attr("headerindex"))
                config.revealdelay=setTimeout(function(){sidemenu.expandone(config["headerclass"], headerindex, config.scrolltoheader)}, config.mouseoverdelay || 0)
            }
            else{
                $(this).trigger("evt_accordion", [true, config.scrolltoheader]) //last parameter indicates this is a direct click on the header
                return false //cancel default click behavior
            }
        })
        $headers.bind("mouseleave", function(){
            clearTimeout(config.revealdelay)
        })
        config.oninit($headers.get(), expandedindices)
        $(window).bind('unload', function(){ //clean up and persist on page unload
            $headers.unbind()
            var expandedindices=[]
            $subcontents.filter(':visible').each(function(index){ //get indices of expanded headers
                expandedindices.push($(this).attr('contentindex'))
            })
            if (config.persiststate==true && $headers.length>0){ //persist state?
                expandedindices=(expandedindices.length==0)? '-1c' : expandedindices //No contents expanded, indicate that with dummy '-1c' value?
                sidemenu.setCookie(config.headerclass, expandedindices)
            }
        })
    })
    }
}

//preload any images defined inside ajaxloadingmsg variable
sidemenu.preloadimages(jQuery(sidemenu.ajaxloadingmsg).filter('img'))
```

Thanks in advance for any help! Alternative solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies are essentially name-value pairs, you can store whatever data you want to in them. Your idea to make each cookie unique by using the URL in the cookie sounds like it would work perfectly (it was my first idea when I was reading your question).